# Are JDK versions released by pair?

Tags: java, version

I've noticed that the JDK versions seems to be released by pair; for example jdk 8u73/8u74, 8u65/8u66, 7u79/7u80, 7u75/7u76, 6u37/6u38.

Is that a pattern or just a coincidence? And what are the differences between theses versions?

(From this page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/8u-relnotes-2225394.html)

Is it related to [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/jdk-version-number-scheme-1918258.html), and if yes, how to identify the versions?